# Refresh SQL query while selecting node in tree every time to display results at some text area in the same page

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-adf

Scenario :

1. I have created 1 tree using standard commands under one region

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
when level = 1 then 1
else -1
end as status, 
level, 
"NAME" as title, 
NULL as icon, 
IDENTIFIER as value, 
"NAME" as tooltip, 
NULL as link 
from owner
start with "PARENT_PAGE_NO" is null
connect by prior "PAGE_NO" = "PARENT_PAGE_NO"
order siblings by "NAME"
```

then i am getting some tree like this as per my db data

Inline image 1

2. Now on the same page i have one text area or say editor which is part of another region in the same page

which have sql command to display some values like

```
select * from owner
where id = :idr --------------item which store value of identifier
```

3. I have one item which fetch value of IDENTIFIER name idr
4. First time value fetch successfully when i select any node but second time on-wards when i select some another node then value didn't refresh.

So this is I want to refresh value every time so i case see results in text area

Comment: Hello! When select any node, page posts/reloads? Have you entered this item name to the "Selected Node Page Item" attribute in tree attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a view link between those two views, then expose the detail view as AccessorIterator, not as Iterator.